# The difference between using command&args to execute shell commands and mounting shell scripts and executing them in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use k8s job to perform some scheduled tasks, as follows:

```yaml
containers:
    - name: container-rgs4wl
      image: 'alpine-curl:3.16.0'
      command:
        - |-
          for i in `cat domains`
          do
              http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`
              curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data  "{\"text\":\"$i check http status  ${http_status}\"}" ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}
          done
```

After completion, it will prompt me the following error:

```
Error: failed to start container "container-rgs4wl": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "for i in `cat domains`；\ndo\n http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`\n curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data \"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"$i check http status ${http_status}\\\"}\" ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}\ndone": stat for i in `cat domains`； do http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i` curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{\"text\":\"$i check http status ${http_status}\"}" ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL} done: no such file or directory: unknown
```

---

When I specify command in `/bin/bash -c`:

```yaml
containers:
    - name: container-ixi4bh
      image: 'harbor.weex.tech/public/alpine-curl:3.16.0'
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - |
          for i in `cat domains` 
          do
              http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`
              curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data  "{\"text\":\"$i check http status  ${http_status}\"}" ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}
          done
```

It prompts the following in the log:

```
 /bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")
```

> When I use the docker run command to execute in a locally started container it works fine.

```bash
$ docker run -ti --rm alpine-curl:3.16.0 sh
/ # for i in `cat domains`
>           do
>               http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`
>               curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data  "{\"text\":\"$i check http status  ${http_st
atus}\"}" ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}
>           done
okokokokokokok/ #
```

> **ok** means normal return.

---

well...well...well...Maybe it's an image problem, I replaced it with `centos:centos7`:

```yaml
containers:
        - name: container-x8ba1n
          image: 'centos:centos7'
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - '-c'
            - |
              for i in `cat domains` 
              do
                  http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`
                  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data  "{\"text\":\"$i check http status  ${http_status}\"}" ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}
              done
```

There are still exceptions, as follows:

```
 /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`'
 /bin/bash: -c: line 1: `    http_status=`curl -I -m 10 -o /dev/null -s -w %{http_code} $i`'
```

Hey...I really don't know the reason, but I finally wrote a shell script and mounted it into the container for execution, this is ok.

```yaml
          containers:
            - name: container-u37d3w
              image: 'centos:centos7'
              command:
                - /bin/bash
              args:
                - /check.sh
              env:
                - name: SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
                  value: >-
                    https://hooks.slack.com/services/...
              resources: {}
              volumeMounts:
                - name: volume-m3lym7
                  readOnly: true
                  mountPath: /domains
                  subPath: domains
                - name: volume-ho9ctd
                  readOnly: true
                  mountPath: /check.sh
                  subPath: check.sh
```

I would like to know what is the difference between using `command` or `args` and executing a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider it like, **command** is like the **command** we run in Linux, for example, **printenv**, **grep**, **echo** and you pass the **argument** into it that's **args**.

like `echo(command) "hello"(args)`

So if you want to run the command in shell you can try something like

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]
```

Or else you can try something like

```
  image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
  command: [ "sh", "-c"]
  args:
  - while true; do
      echo -en '\n';
      printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
      sleep 10;
    done;
  env:
```

You can read more about : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/_print/